# Problem appending to ManyToMany form field when cleaning data

Tags: django

Just moved from Django 1.00 to 1.30 and I'm suddenly getting an error during form validation:

```
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'append'
```

The code is below.  While cleaning the list of coordinators specified by the user in the form, I want to include all super-users as well.

The problem seems to be that the cleaned_data.get() call is returning a QuerySet. I thought it returned an object representing the field type.  As I said above, this code used to work in 1.0, but maybe that was an accident.

Can someone tell me what cleaned_data.get is returning in this case and how I can add other values to it?

Thanks.

```
class Party(models.Model):
    coordinators = models.ManyToManyField( 'PersonProfile', blank=True, related_name='event_coordinator_set', help_text='' )

class PartyForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Party

    def __init__( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        super( PartyForm, self ).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['coordinators'].queryset = PersonProfile.objects.exclude( user__is_superuser=1 )

    def clean_coordinators( self ):
        coordinators = self.cleaned_data.get( 'coordinators', '' )
        superuser_list = PersonProfile.objects.filter( user__is_superuser=1 )
        for superuser in superuser_list:
            coordinators.append( superuser )
        return coordinators
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def clean_coordinators( self ):
    coordinators = self.cleaned_data.get( 'coordinators', '' )
    if coordinators:
        return PersonProfile.objects.filter(
            Q(pk__in=coordinators) | Q(user__is_superuser=1)
        )
    else:
        return PersonProfile.objects.filter(user__is_superuser=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you found out it was a `QuerySet`, you could have just turned the queryset into a list and leave the rest of your code intact... `coordinatiors = list(myqueryset)`, but I would recommend Thierry's solution.

Anyho, you're right: I looked at django 1.0, and `ModelMultipleChoiceField` used to return a list. Now, it returns a `QuerySet`.

#### Django 1.0 ModelMultipleChoiceField.clean()

```
final_values = []
for val in value:
    try:
        obj = self.queryset.get(pk=val)
    except self.queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
        raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_choice'] % val)
    else:
        final_values.append(obj)
return final_values
```

#### Django 1.3 ModelMultipleChoiceField.clean()

```
    for pk in value:
        try:
            self.queryset.filter(**{key: pk})
        except ValueError:
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_pk_value'] % pk)
    qs = self.queryset.filter(**{'%s__in' % key: value})
    pks = set([force_unicode(getattr(o, key)) for o in qs])
    for val in value:
        if force_unicode(val) not in pks:
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_choice'] % val)
    # Since this overrides the inherited ModelChoiceField.clean
    # we run custom validators here
    self.run_validators(value)
    return qs
```